# How to get user account uuid MacOS (not machine uuid) via terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash

I need to get the user's UUID by username from the terminal (not the machine itself, but the local user).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand which one: There is the UniqueID and the GeneratedUID, which you can find with one or the other: `dscl . -list /Users UniqueID` `dscl . -list /Users GeneratedUID`, then just grep for the username.

Comment: @Redarm, you should out that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than getting all users' IDs and searching for the right one, you can use `dscl /Search -read` to get just the specific user's info:

```
dscl /Search -read "/Users/$USER" GeneratedUID
```

This will print something like "GeneratedUID: B8A467BD-BCB8-47ED-9335-E0C187628DA7". If you want *just* the UUID itself, you can pipe it through `cut`:

```
dscl /Search -read "/Users/$USER" GeneratedUID | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which UID you are looking for (since there is the "UniqueID" and the "GeneratedUID"), you can find them with either...

```
dscl . -list /Users UniqueID
```

...or...

```
dscl . -list /Users GeneratedUID
```

You can then also search by username; e.g. for the logged in user:

```
dscl . -list /Users GeneratedUID | grep $(whoami)
```

Or if you only wanted the UUID, without the username printed, you could use `awk` to print only the UID; e.g.

```
dscl . -list /Users GeneratedUID | grep $(whoami) | awk '{print $2}'
```

...or instead of `$(whoami)` you could fill in the username you are looking for.
(I only listed the GeneratedUID for the examples above, as it's just a simple swap of expressions, i.e. just put UniqueID instead, if that's the UID you are after.)

Comment: Nice!  I prefer CLI over GUI any day.  CLI stays pretty consistent across multiple versions of macOS whereas the GUI is in constant flux. Besides, you can always script CLI much easier (IMO) than AS.